# countrycode() doesn't recognize Kosovo?

Tags: r, country-codes

I think I found a bug or rather a missing update in the package `countrycode`:

```
library(countrycode)
testData <- data.frame(country=c(rep("Germany",3),rep("Kosovo",3)))
testData$iso3 <- countrycode(testData$country, "country.name", "iso3c")
```

which is problematic not only for political reasons but also because international organizations such as the IMF or the BIS do include Kosovo in their datasets. Countrycode will produce `NA's` here.

What do I do with this information? The iso3c should be KSV I think.

EDIT: I contacted the package maintainer who replied that until Kosovo is recognized officially, he'd rather keep it this way.

Comment: Contact package maintainer - `Vincent Arel-Bundock <vincent.arel-bundock at umontreal.ca>`

Comment: Kosovo is not a universally recognised country and consequently is not part of the standards: http://unstats.un.org/unsd/tradekb/Knowledgebase/Country-Code and https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search

Comment: but it shows up in universally recognized datasets which people are working with

Comment: @rbm The package doesn’t seem to have a bug.

Comment: i think your comment was meant for @PeterPan

Comment: @rbm No, you suggested contacting the package maintainer … I thought your implication was that the package had a bug.

Comment: The original post ended with "What do I do with this information?" so I suggested he contacted the owner to discuss with Vincent. OP later edited the post (after he'd contacted the owner).

Comment: I'll still keep it undeleted for google. Others might have the same problem and now we have an answer

Comment: I am the maintainer. Previous comment is correct. The ISO standard does not include a code for Kosovo. Therefore, it would be incorrect to include one in countrycode. I know that certain organizations create ad hoc codes, but those must be treated on an ad hoc basis by the analyst. A pain, I know...

Comment: Issues can be discussed on github: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You requested ISO country codes, and ISO simply has no code assigned for Kosovo. FIPS has, though:

```
> countrycode('Kosovo', 'country.name', 'fips104')
[1] "KV"
```

If you want “KSV” as the result, you could use the World Bank code instead:

```
> countrycode('Kosovo', 'country.name', 'wb')
[1] "KSV"
```

Comment: nice! thanks! I usually work in ISO codes thats why the problem arose.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert to iso3c, but **also** convert Kosovo to KSV at the same time, you can use the `countrycode` parameter `custom_match`...

```
library(countrycode)

testData <- data.frame(country=c(rep("Germany",3),rep("Kosovo",3)))

countrycode(testData$country, "country.name", "iso3c", 
            custom_match = c(Kosovo = "KSV"))
#[1] "DEU" "DEU" "DEU" "KSV" "KSV" "KSV"
```